# Extract text between two <hr> tags in CSS-less HTML

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Using Jsoup, what would be an optimal approach to extract text, of which its pattern is known (`[number]%%[number]`) but resides in an HTML page that uses neither CSS nor divs, spans, classes or other identifying of any type (yup, old HTML page of which I have no control over)?

The only thing that consistently identifies that text segment (and is guaranteed to remain like that) is that is HTML *always* looks like this (within a larger body of HTML):

```
<hr>
2%%17
<hr>
```

(The number 2 and 17 are examples only. They could be any numbers and, in fact, these are the two variables that I need to reliably extract from that HTML page).

If that text were within an enclosing and uniquely identifying `<span>` or `<div>`, I would have no problem extracting it using Jsoup. The problem is that this isn't the case and the only way I can think of right now (which is *not* elegant at all) is to process the **raw** HTML through a regex.

Processing the raw HTML through a regex seems inefficient however because I already have it parsed via Jsoup into a DOM.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried debugging the jsoup element to see if the elements are there?

Comment: @ariel Yes, the elements are there but they are *not* "enclosing elements", so I can't really use `element.text()` to get the much covetted `[number]%%[number]`. :)

Comment: @ariel Problem is `[number]%%[number]` is *not* an element. So, for now, my workaround is to take `body.html()` and pass it through a regex that identifies the above described pattern. But I am open to more elegant solutions.

Comment: so the element isnt there. it's not parsed as an element, its only on the body

Comment: Does that pattern occur multiple times in HTML? Or only once?

Comment: @BalusC This pattern occurs only once in the HTML, fortunately. There are quite a few `<hr>` elements in the HTML but only one with the pattern I quoted in my post.

Comment: There are no other elements between `<hr>`s? Even no `<p>`? Just `<hr>blahblah 2%%17 blahblah</hr>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements hrs = document.select("hr");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+%%\\d+)");

for (Element hr : hrs) {
    String textAfterHr = hr.nextSibling().toString();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textAfterHr);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // <-- There, your data.
    }
}
```

Comment: There is certainly more jsoup in this solution but since it has to resort to regex anyway, the question now is whether passing body.HTML() through the regex would be faster.

Comment: You're looking for patterns inside a text node. Jsoup can't do much for you as it is not a regex matcher.

Comment: Of course. But I'm curious now as to whether looping through hrs is faster than top level regex.

Comment: Something like (<hr>)\s*(\d+)%%(\d+)\s*(<hr>)

Comment: Regex will at least be faster if the to-be-matched string is as small as possible. Passing the *entire* document through it instead of only the smallest possible snippets of which you're certain that it can contain the data you're looking for would be more expensive.